# Django - counting foreign keys in models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I know how I can count things with annotate (in my view) but I would like to do the same in model (so it would be more reusable).

For example (lets take an example from django documentation) I have this model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pubdate = models.DateField()

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

and I can use in view this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
```

But how I do that in model?
I know this question is pretty basic (probably) but I'm pretty much beginner in django.
Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom managers:

[Django docs: Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/)

```
class BookManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(num_books=Count('book'))

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    books = BookManager()
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
pubs = Publisher.books.all()
```

And you will have `num_books` with your objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **classmethod** for this.

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def get_book_count(cls):
        return cls.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
```

You can call this method as

```
pubs = Publisher.get_book_count()
```

Edit - Also check out the answer by @Navid2zp which might be a better solution for you.